# Variable naming: member identification vs ease of use

Tags: c++

I'm writing a little library for myself which has a class that contains hexfields with their cube coordinates x,y and z. Now I usually mark my member variables with a leading m, e.g. int mPosition; or mX, mY, mZ, in this specific case. This would lead to the getter being named getmX().

This is pretty straightforward, but is somehow not as readable as getX(). Would you say it is acceptable to use mX in the class, but rename the publically visible getter to getX()? Or is there a reason to stay consistent? There will not be a publically available setter.

Comment: What are "hexfields"? What are "cube coordinates"?

Comment: Seems very subjective here. Personally, I think getX() or even getXCoord() would be fine to use.

Comment: Usually, the getters and setters are constructed with `get`/`set` + VariableName. It's a pretty common convention

Comment: Simple do what you or your company want but always in the same way. It really unimportant how you do it!

Comment: @AlexTartan: Read more closely!

Comment: Hex fields is just the short form of hexagonal fields, commonly used in strategy games or role playing games. Since they have 6 neighbors you can't simply use x and y coordinates, instead you view them as arranged in a 3 dimensional cube and give them x,y and z coordinates. It's not relevant at all for the question, though :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> This would lead to the getter being named getmX().

No, it wouldn't.

- The entity is "called" `x`.
- The member variable you used to represent that entity is `mX`.
- The getter function you used to access that entity is `getX()`.

I wouldn't go too far down the path of getters and setters, though; they're a bit of an anti-pattern when only thinly wrapping individual variables like this.

Besides, call it whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense to me. This ways I feel I get the most mileage for me and possibly other people having to use the code at some point.

Comment: @Draugr: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12108025/560648) is a good read.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at that.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that private variables have a leading m is an implementation detail, clients shouldn't rely on it.

Your getters are public and should never change even if you change your implementation.
Therefore, it's not a question of being easy to use. You should write getX() for better encapsulation.

Comment: _"You should write getX() for better encapsulation."_ huh

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes? Do you disagree?

Comment: I don't see what "encapsulation" has to do with it, is all.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm just saying, if he's strict about naming his getters after the exact name of the member it's getting, then he can't change the name of the member variable without changing the signature of "getmX()". By naming the function "getX()", he can name his member however he wants and rename it without breaking client code